# post kendo editor value as html rich text

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I have noticed a problem with Kendo ui editot when posting (via ajax)  editor.value() rich html text to the server.

when posting a few lines with html design -> in the server I get only the first line until the first '&nbsp'.

```
$("#emailTxtEditor").kendoEditor({
    //encoded: false,
    resizable: true
 });
```

for instance I take [This Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/KuQvs/424/) and after designing some text the post missing lot's of the html content...

ps, in the server there is no model becuase i don't save this content.
How can resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#emailTxtEditor").kendoEditor(
        {
            tools:
              [
                  "bold",
                  "italic",
                  .....
              ],
            messages: {
                bold: "Bold",
                italic: "Italic",
                underline: "Underline",
                ....
            },
            encoded: false,                
            keyup: function () {
                $("#YourTextbox").val(encodeURIComponent($("#emailTxtEditor").data("kendoEditor").value())),
                $("#YourTextbox").focusin()
            },
            change: function () {
                $("#YourTextbox").val(encodeURIComponent($("#emailTxtEditor").data("kendoEditor").value())),
                $("#YourTextbox").focusin()
            }
        })
```

And in controller:

```
var emailContent = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Email.EmailContent);//Email is model (for ex)
```